# Simple Closed Curve Homotopic to Circle Around Interior Point

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I’m trying to formalize some claims made about simple closed curves in my complex analysis course (its treatment of them is informal since facts like the Jordan curve theorem are so hard to prove.) One fact that is intuitively obvious to me, but which I’m having trouble proving, is the following:

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be a simple closed curve, and let $z_0$ Be a point inside $\gamma$. (I’m assuming we’ve already established the Jordan Curve Theorem.) Then $\gamma$ is homotopic as a closed curve in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_0\}$ to a circle centered at $z_0$, traversed either once counterclockwise or once clockwise.

My initial idea is to continuously project $\gamma$ onto a circle centered at $z_0$, and then show that the projected curve can be “straighted out” on the circle. But I’m not sure how to do that. I’m guessing we need some more sophisticated topological tools — is there a way to do this with the fundamental group? I’d like to avoid using homology if possible, since my knowledge on it is spotty at best. Or if the continuous case is too difficult, I’m willing to settle for the case that $\gamma$ is piecewise $C^1$.

Comment: $\gamma$ is actually a map from the unit circle $[0,1]/(0=1)$ and let $J$ its image (so the curve); JCT implies that (the function) $\gamma$ extends to a continuous injective map $f$ from the closed unit disc to $\bar U=J \cup \text {int} J$ and one can insure by composing with a disc automorphism that $f(0)=z_0$; from there the result should be clear

Comment: @Conrad How does the JCT give us the map $f$?

Comment: Here I may have been a bit sloppy as I meant that there is a parametrization of $J$ which does so (this follows from JCT); in  other words if $J$ is a Jordan curve there is a continuous bijective map $f:S^1 \to J$ that extends to a homeomorphism between the closed unit disc and $J$ with its interior

Comment: @Conrad Ok that makes sense. And how does the the map $f$ give us the desired homotopy between $\gamma$ and a circle?

Comment: $f$ shows that the winding number of $J$ around $z_0$ is $\pm 1$ depending on orientation (if you want a more "hands-on" approach, you can use complex analysis, get the map above analytic by RMT, move everything back to the unit disc, so $J$ becomes the unit circle and the preimage of the circle, an analytic curve circling zero, approximate the analytic curve by a PL one, make the corresponding polygon convex by straightening angles over $180$ and use stright lines from the center to the boundary)

Comment: The whole point of JCT (at least imho) is that any Jordan curve (which can be crazy -see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve) can be pulled back to the unit circle by a "nice" map on its interior (as noted one can take such map analytic by RMT) so anything "nice" inside its interior, gets pulled back to something nice in the unit disc too